# Bootstrap main body is overlapping the header and not centered

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys i am tryng to create a websie with bootstrap for the first time and trying to sort out the basic layout. However i am having two problems right now.

1st My main body which i have colored in white is not in the middle of the page. 
I am trying to make the main page look something like this :

```
 -----------------------------------------------
|    |                          |              |
|-----------------------------------------------                        
|    |Logo               Nav Bar|              |
|-----------------------------------------------                        
|    |                           |             |
|    |                           |             |
|    |      Body                 |             |
|    |                           |             |
|    |                           |             |
|-----------------------------------------------                        
|    |Logo          Info        |              |
|-----------------------------------------------                        
|    |                          |              |
 -----------------------------------------------
```

However for some reason the body is stuck to the left and not in the middle.

My second problem is the nav bar at the top. Because its not stuck right at the top it means when i scroll , the white body will overlap it when i go down and this is a big problem. If the nav bar was stuck right at the top this is not an issue however i would like my navbar to be not at the top but like 80px down.

Any help on this would be great.

HTML:

```
<div class="mainHome">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

Comment: Slightly difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve, by default most elements are full width. Try wrapping everything in another .container div.

Comment: Not sure what u mean, like i just want my main body which i colored in white to be in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this.

```
<div class="container" id="main-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="logo">
              <img src="Image/Logo.png" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="login.php">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#about">Become A member</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainHome">
          <div class="container">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">   
          <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
            <p> &copy 2016 </p>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and add this CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#main-container {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap requires that all content is inside a containing element, which can have the class "container" or "container-fluid". From there you need to use the Bootstrap grid system, using rows and then columns. So your structure will be of the form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            /* content here */
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in your code, the "container" class must be the outermost division, with everything else inside it.

You can learn about the basics of the Bootstrap grid system here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container